# If the a specific column is checked how to transform the other columns into NA

Tags: r, if-statement

```
id<-1:3
varNA<-c(1,1,0)
var1<-c(0,0,1)
var2<-c(0,0,0)
var3<-c(0,0,1)

mydata<-data.frame(id,varNA, var1, var2, var3)
```

If the column `varNA==1`, that is checked, I want to transform all the remaining columns in NA for the individual.

```
 varNA  var1  var2  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA    NA    NA
2     1    NA    NA    NA
3     0     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```r
library(tidyverse)

id<-1:3
varNA<-c(1,1,0)
var1<-c(0,0,1)
var2<-c(0,0,0)
var3<-c(0,0,1)

mydata<-data.frame(id,varNA, var1, var2, var3)


mydata %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = var1:var3) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(varNA == 1, NA, value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(c(id,varNA)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   varNA  var1  var2  var3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1    NA    NA    NA
#> 2     1    NA    NA    NA
#> 3     0     1     0     1
```